# Import PHP style guides to PhpStorm to automaticlly structure code?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

We have a really sloppy codebase and I would like to structure it a bit e.g fix all wrongly intended lines and fix such: `$sum=1+1` to `$sum = 1 + 1`.

Is there a way to do this? I have a faint memory that I did something similar with IntelliJ but with googles style guides for java.

Comment: There are `rearrange` and `reformat` options in phpstorm. and you can fully configurate php style in phpstorm. But thing you have to do it manuel: open file, click rearrange and save file again.

Comment: Your code will not be reformatted automatically -- only with your consent (that's the general idea that devs at JB are sticking to at the moment). You can invoke it manually at any time `Code | Reformat Code`. To configure it -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style`

Comment: Yea this is exactly what I was looking for. But for java we could download googles style guides to reformat to. Is there something similar for php?

Comment: There are [several predefined styles](http://i.imgur.com/6YnFGdV.png) you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking: your code will not be reformatted automatically (like Visual Studio may do as you type) -- only with your consent (that's the general idea that devs at JetBrains are sticking to at the moment). Although current formatting rules are used when you insert some elements from Code Completion popup/Live Template.

You can invoke code formatter manually at any time via `Code | Reformat Code`.

To configure formatting rules -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP`.

It also allows to use some predefined formatting styles (like `PEAR, Zend, WordPress, Symfony 2 etc.) by importing it into your current scheme (use`Set from:` clickable link on the right top side of that screen):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/code-style-php.html#d14191e93

[image]

---

PHP language also has support for code re-arrangement (`Arrangement` tab) -- it allows you to specify how your entities/class elements will be placed in your code (fields first then methods; public methods first and private at the end; etc).

Code arrangement can be executed without invoking actual code formatting -- use `Code | Rearrange Code` for that.